# When using lagrange multipliers why does computing $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ give a mix or a min ( I do not understand the concept entirely)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Why should it be that when $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are parallel, that at this point there is a max or a min?

Comment: we need $v\cdot\nabla f=0$ for every vector $v$ tangent to $g=0$, i.e. for every $v$ such that $v\cdot\nabla g=0$. That's equivalent to $\nabla f$ being a multiple of $\nabla g$ (provided $\nabla g\neq 0$, which is a condition one needs to use anyway).

Comment: unfortunately that answer doesn't quite do it for me? Maybe phrased in a better way is. If im at the pt where $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are parallel, why is it that this point must be a max or a min?

Comment: $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$ doesn't imply that $f$ has max or min at the point; it just means that the derivatives in direction tangent to the constraint are zero. Just as $\nabla f=0$ doesn't mean max or min if there are no constraints.